# SVN Create Branch from Uncommited Code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn

I’m new to SVN. I have a project that I’m adding new feature too and it has taken longer than I thought [*surprise not]. Now some production code needs fixing. How can I save my uncommitted “new feature” code as a new Branch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the command line tool, go to the root of your working copy and perform the following steps:

First create a new (feature) branch in the repository. The following command has no effect on your working copy:

```
svn copy ^/hello/trunk ^/hello/branches/feature-foobar
```

Now move your working copy with all uncommitted changes to the feature branch and commit the changes:

```
svn switch ^/hello/branches/feature-foobar
svn commit
```

Move your working copy back to the trunk and start working on the bug fix:

```
svn switch ^/hello/trunk
```

Later you go back to the feature branch, complete your changes and reintegrate them with the trunk.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the branch before committing the code, make sure you are on it, then add and commit your changes.

Comment: What do you mean by " on it, then add..." I created a new directory in the (To Path:) in Tortoise. Selected Create copy from Working copy. Said Ok then got an error about the directory already existed.